# Web API returns XML and Json, only want Json

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, mongodb-.net-driver

Hi I am trying to create web api that I can call to view all the documents in the MongoDB, now the documents are very large and are heavily nested, I have Managed to return the document but in Json with the headers in XML.

I need to return this entire thing in Json!

This code takes the BsonDocument Product and returns this as Json because without this I get an error:

```
[JsonIgnore]
        public BsonDocument Product { get; set; }

[DataMember]
        public string Product
        {
            get { return Product .ToJson(); }
            set { Product = BsonDocument.Parse(value); }
        }
```

Here is a sample of the Document(This is a basic example, the actual document is much larger with deeper levels:

```
{
    "product": {
        "Type": "Phone",
            "Size": {
            "Height": 10,
                "Lenght": 5,
                "Weight": 30
        }
        "Make": "Apple"
        "Model": {
            "Name": "IPhone",
                "Range": "4s"
        }

    }
}
```

it returns as

```
<Product>
{"product": {"Type": "Phone","Size": {"Height": 10,"Lenght": 5,"Weight": 30}"Make": "Apple", "Model": {"Name": "IPhone","Range": "4s"}}}
</Product>
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i fix this?

Like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...
    // This will contain the JSON you want to return to the client
    string product = model.Product;

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StringContent(product, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, do I put this in my product class which contains the first snippet of code in my question?

Comment: No, you put this in your Web API controller action which is supposed to serve this JSON.

Comment: I see, so what would MyViewModel be?

Comment: I don't know. That's up to you. The important thing is to have some string property containing the JSON that you would pass to the `StringContent` constructor as shown in my answer. Where this is coming from is entirely your business.